# Set an array to be displayed at Chart js

Tags: javascript, arrays, charts, chart.js

For example i have the array [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13] and i only want to display the subarray [5,6,7,8,9].

Is this posible using the Chart.js library?

EDIT: Fiirst of all i am showing the complete array on the chart. After clicking a button, i will have the subarray displayed. Any ideas of to do so?

Comment: `var newAr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13].splice(4,5)`

Comment: no. you didnt understand the question. I mean, i have that array displayed on a chart. and i want to show the subarray on the chart.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to just destroy the chart (using the chart variable) and construct a new chart using the new data.

For instance, if you already have constructed it using

```
...
var ctx = document.getElementById("chart").getContext("2d");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx).Bar(data);
```

You need to destroy it first using

```
myChart.destroy();
```

and then make the new chart

```
myChart = new Chart(ctx).Bar(newData);
```

where `newData` is the new data object.

You could also update the old data object (if you are not using it for anything else) instead of using a new object, like so

```
data.labels = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]; 
data.datasets[0].data = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]; 
myChart.destroy();
myChart = new Chart(ctx).Bar(data);
```

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/5u3ahg7L/

(the chart updates with the new data after a 2 second delay, you don't need the setTimeout wrapper - it's just for demonstration)

---

You could also do this using the prototype methods `.update()` and `.removeData()` (http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#line-chart-prototype-methods for Line chart methods - each type has the similar methods) but since your changes require you to remove data from both ends of the graph, `.destroy()` would be an easier option.